# Angular 2 move element animation

Tags: angular, css, angular-animations

I have a list of items with `*ngFor`.
I want to animate an item moving up when a button inside the element is clicked.
How do I do this with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what your mind expected, somehow I have managed to create a simple example, 
but here i dont know hot to create an angular example, so i made one in stackblitz. 
[Checkout the stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpbdee)

Comment: Awesome! Tweaked it a bit and it works great for my needs. Thanks!